# Listpaging in Sencha Touch using 'offset' instead of 'page'

Tags: pagination, paging, offset, sencha-touch-2.2

I am using listpaging plugin on a list and would like to use it with an 'offset' value. The API that I'm running against doesn't support pagination with 'page' values but rather uses offsets.

If I have a limit of 10 and offset 0, I will get the first 10 records, with limit 10 and offset 10, I will get records 11-20 and so on.

The listpaging plugin though requires a 'page' value. I have tried setting the startParam to 'offset' on my store proxy but this results in loading records 1-11 rather than 11-20.

Any suggestions?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Retailers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        storeId: 'retailersStore',
        model: 'MyApp.model.Retailer',
        pageSize: 10,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'myapp/api/retailers',
            startParam: 'offset',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'data.entries',
                totalProperty: 'count'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that, as well as the `startParam`, you need to set the `limitParam`

Comment: I have the same issue, even with the `limitParam`. I find that on the first request, it sends page, limit and start. On subsequent requests (scrolling down) it only sends page. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265738-Listpaging-with-offset-value-instead-of-page-number&p=989914#post989914

Comment: Update: I was setting `startParam` and `limitParam` incorrectly to integer values instead of to the names of the parameters, when these are both set it does work for me! Doh.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can add `pageParam: 'customPageParamName'` property to `proxy` and voilà.

Hope this helps.